# Typeset an = with an ! above

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I've seen an equals sign with a small exclamation mark on top being used to say "equals because of data that was given in the problem", for example for a boundary condition or initial value in a differential equation.

A rough picture of what I mean:

```
     !
f(x) = 4
```

How do I typeset this in LaTeX? I've tried $=^!$ (which doesn't produce the desired result) and looked through the "relations" section of the [Comprehensive List of Symbols](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) without success.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

That's very easy. And there are at least two identical solutions.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \[
   a\stackrel{!}{=} b   % from vanilla LaTeX
 \]

 \[
   a\overset{!}{=} b    % from »amsmath«
 \]
\end{document}
```

Both give identical output in this case but `\overset` should be preferred because it takes care of operator spacing.

Comment: Is there any reason to use the ams solution over the plain TeX version?

Comment: »amsmath« is *always* preferable.

Comment: in most cases, it's preferable *for some reason*!  For my part I'm not skeptical that it is better here, but I would be interested to know in what ways it's better :-)

Comment: @Peter: when you use `amsmath`, `\stackrel` can be considered obsolete as `\overset` does the same thing better, because it gives correct spacing with binary operators (like `+`, `\oplus`, etc.) and ordinary symbols.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: The output is ugly when I want to put a questionmark over equals sign, because "?" is too high above "=". How can I make it appear lower, right above "="?

Answer (score 26):

```
\stackrel#1#2
```

is the command you search.

```
\stackrel{!}{=}
```

will lead to the sign you want to typeset. The first argument sits on top of the second argument, where the first one is smaller than the second one.

Answer (score 17):

If you needed to customize the separation between the overset, here's a way it could be done.  The default is 3pt, halfway between the two examples shown.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
 a \mathrel{\stackon[5pt]{$=$}{$\scriptstyle!$}} b
\quad
 a \mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{$=$}{$\scriptstyle!$}} b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

just to add another one....

```
\mathop{=}\limits^!
```

Comment: Also fine! Just the spacing is too tight for a relation symbol, but you could add `\mathrel` around the expression.

Comment: This is perfect. A quick explanation of what is going on would be nice though. E.g. what does the `limits` do?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an oldie goldie

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ a \buildrel!\over= b \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To reduce typing and opportunity for syntax errors, it is better to place a frequently used typesetting algorithm inside a macro. Rather than type

```
    \[
        a\overset{!}{=} b
    \]
```

for each equation, one might utilize a macro in the preamble

```
    \newcommand{\XoverE}{\ensuremath{\overset{!}{=}}}
```

and use it thusly

```
    $a\XoverE{}b$
```

For myself, I use the following macro for an overset question mark:

```
    \newcommand{\?}{\ensuremath{\overset{?}{-}}}
```

then

```
    $a\?{}b$
```

*Edited*

Comment: Try to use it in text mode and you'll have a nasty surprise `:-)` This works in math mode because of a happy coincidence, since `\ensuremath` basically becomes `\@firstofone`. However, in text mode this becomes `$relax\overset${!}{=}` and goes quite wrong. Either you enclose the whole `\overset` construction in braces or (IMNSHO better) you eliminate `\ensuremath` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can define custom commands using special characters for the `\stackrel` approach.

```
\catcode`\!=11
\newcommand{\eq!}{\stackrel{?}{=}}
% ...
$f(x) \eq! 4$
```

It is also nice to define `\leq?`, `\mid?` etc.

This solution is significantly better than writing `\stackrel{?}{=}` and friends frequently.

Comment: You'll regret doing this when `$x/\!y$` will throw you a strange error.

Comment: @egreg Why? Just write `$x/!y$`

Comment: That's a different thing.