# Question mark over equals sign

Tags: symbols

I'd like to have output an equals sign that has a small question mark over the top of it. (I'm proving an equation, but it is not obvious until the final step that the equation is true.)

Do I need to create a special symbol myself (via a macro, etc.), or is there already one defined?

Comment: See [Typeset an = with an ! above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/typeset-an-with-an-above).

Comment: @Caramdir: I'm voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: That's only a duplicate if you already know that the answer is "set one above the other yourself".

Comment: This is Unicode U+225F, and with the `unicode-math` package, a sutable font, and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX can be accessed as `\questeq`.

Comment: @krlmlr below is correct that the solution from the duplicate/linked question is better. To save time for those who Googled to get here (like me), the solution from the linked question uses `amsmath` and then, within the math environment, the following command: `a\overset{?}{=} b`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Use the following command within the math environment (`$ <command> $`):

`\stackrel{?}{=}`.

Comment: On point. Nothing more, nothing less. I define `\newcommand{\?}{\stackrel{?}{=}}` to make things go faster.

Comment: @jimi- it gave an error, ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 \?

Comment: @Aku: It has to be used within the math environment for it to work and that's where I assumed you were working, anyway ;) If you typed `$ l.5 \?`, then I think you're simply missing the closing `$` symbol! Otherwise, it should work fine.

Comment: Note that the [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/typeset-an-with-an-above) mentions `\overset` from `amsmath` which is preferable over `\stackrel` according to Philippe Goutet. Care to edit your reply? (I googled for "question mark over equals sign" and hence don't think the question should be closed as duplicate ;-) )