# How to type specific things on the hat of expression?

Tags: math-operators

I have problem typing this on the hat of `max` in the following example:

[image]

Comment: See [Typeset an `=` with an `!` above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6195/5764). Depending on the context, `\[ \max_{j=1}^{|B|} ... \]` should suffice, since `\max` is an operator where the limits are set below/above when in display math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
\[
\max_{j=1}^{|B|}
\]
```

Comment: Please don't use `$$` notation for LaTeX documents. For much more information on this subject see, e.g., [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between $$, \\[, align, equation and displaymath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001).

Answer (score 3):

Following egreg's suggestion, for math operators that are not defined by default, one can use `\operatorname*{...}_{...}^{...}`. Or, for typesetting math texts that are not math operators, you can also use the `\overset` (and `\underset`) command of the `AMSmath` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \max_{j=1}^{|B|} 
  \qquad
  \operatorname*{argmax}_{j=1}^{|B|}
\]

\[
  \underset{j=1}{\overset{|B|}{math \; texts \; \mbox{and regular texts in math mode}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\operatorname*{maximize}_{j=1}^{|B|}`