# How to write letter above $\nabla$ sign?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

I am interested in writing the following symbol. Please give me code.

Thank you so much in advanced.

[image]

Comment: With the `accents` package, you can use `\accentset{\mathrm h}{\nabla}`.

Comment: @Bernard - You should write this up as an answer.

Comment: @Bernard Looks more like `\mathtt` to me, but as Mico said...

Comment: @Mico: done, my lord. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Typeset an = with an ! above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6195/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the `accents` package is your friend for this kind of problems:

```
$\accentset{\mathrm{h}}{\nabla}$
```

or maybe, as @campa suggested with `\mathtt`:

[image]

Comment: @egred: Thanks for the edit! One never re-reads oneself carefully enough…

Answer (score 3):

Using `overset` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\overset{\mathtt{h}}{\nabla} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]